# Calling Array Function

Tags: php, arrays, function

How do I create an input argument and call the function defined below?

```
function insert_data ($var) {
    $set_entry_array = array(
        array('name' => 'name' ,'value' => $var['phone']),
        array('name' => 'email' ,'value' => $var['circle']),                    
        array('name' => 'assigned_user_id' ,'value' => 1),
    );
}
```

I want to call this function to pass the actual value in the name and email parameter.

Comment: To call a function just use its name along with some parameters

Comment: It's not even clear what that function intends to do, it would just return true

Answer (score 2):

Your function accepts an array. You need to define the array, and pass it to the function. It appears the function expects two array keys to be set: ***phone*** and ***circle***. We need to set them.

```
$myarray = array();
$myarray['phone'] = '555-1234';
$myarray['circle'] = 'foo@bar.com';

insert_data($myarray);
```

Comment: hi when i am calling this function just below its declaration the way you said. its throwing me error
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\wamp"

Note: I have  function __construct(){} as well in the same class

how can i call this function from outside of my class?

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question, and give us some example code. Please accept the answer for this one and post a new question.